# Mono DllNotFound error

Tags: linux, mono

I find myself unable to run any WinForms applications in Mono 3.0 (on OpenSUSE 12.3 x64). The problem I get is `System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so`. The reason it's not find libgdiplus.so is that it's not in `/usr/local/lib` on my system but rather `/usr/lib64`. I know for a fact that `/usr/lib64` is in ldconfig's path, and I've also tried changing the dllmap entries for gdiplus in `/etc/mono/config` to point directly at it, and the error persists.

I have a complete log of trying to run MoMA with `MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug"` [here.](http://pastebin.com/71j8F2ns) It seems to be ignoring the config file and looking directly for the SO in the wrong place.

Is there any way to make it look for this SO in the right place?

Comment: Is your application a 64-bit or a 32-bit application?

Comment: I am assuming that you have run `ldconfig -v` to update the libraries? It should also print out the paths so that you can confirm that `/usr/lib64` is hit.

Comment: @chue-x Yes, I did run ldconfig and `/usr/lib64` is in the list. Also, libgdiplus.so specifically is in ldconfig's list of libraries. @Timo neither-- it's .NET bytecode and can be run on any platform that has Mono or the .NET Framework.

Comment: @PrinceBilliard - interesting. Can you try adding a symlink from `/usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so` to `usr/lib64`?

Comment: @chue-x the symlink works, as expected, but if Mono looks for other libraries in the wrong place in the future, I don't want to fill `usr/local/lib` with symlinks. I'd like to address the root cause if possible.

Comment: @PrinceBilliard - understood.

Answer (score 3):

@PrinceBilliard - the root cause is a change to */data/config.in* that added the (partially) hard-coded path to libgdiplus.so.  The real fix would be to modify the source code to remove the path from the entry, leaving just *libgdiplus.so* in the entry.
If you have a path in the config file, Mono will use that path and ignore the ldconfig cache and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Without a path, Mono will try the library name with different suffixes as well as referring to the ldconfig cache and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

The way I dealt with it in my package spec was to add a %post task to edit /mono/config and strip out the path from the entry.   RobFlum